# is it possible to move a div inside another div using jquery without re-rendering the html?

Tags: jquery

Okay, I might confuse some people who might be able to answer this question, I'll set this in the manner that I understand. Please bear with me.

Let's say I have an array of divs in this manner:

```
<div id="par1"><span>Text 1</span></div>
<div id="par2"><span>Text 1</span></div>
<div id="par3"><span>Text 1</span></div>
<div id="par4"><span>Text 1</span></div>
```

Then, I have a hidden div with a textbox that acts like an editor:

```
<div id="editor" style="display: hidden"><input id="uniqueID$textbox" type="text" /></div>
```

What I want to achieve in jQuery is to **visually** display the **#editor** div within the divs above when i click each div somewhat an editor. Instead of having seperate input boxes within those divs and displaying them when needed, I intend to just use one textbox for each.

I hope I explained my problem well and hope you guys can help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to replace the `<span>` with an `<input>` element on click, like

```
$(function(){
  $('span').bind('click', function(){
     $(this).replaceWith($('<input/>', {
        id:       'newinp',
        type:     'text',
        focusout: function(){
           $(this).replaceWith('<span>' + $(this).val() + '</span>');
        }
     }));       
     $('#newinp').focus();
  });
});​
```

Working example: http://www.jsfiddle.net/qbDKN/

Answer (score 1):

You can't avoid re-rendering HTML but I suspect you simply meant re-rendering the entire page. Certainly possible in JS, in jquery I believe you want a combination of `detach()` and one of the `append()` / `prepend()` / `*pendTo()` methods as per the documentation example [here](http://api.jquery.com/detach/).

Comment: it kills the telerik control. are there other ways?

Comment: This is the crux of the problem with asp.net webforms - the damned thing oversteps it's bounds and you have to do everything it's way or not at all. I suggest you wrap all of this in an updatepanel, there's no other way I know of to manipulate part of a page and maintain the asp.net view model.

Answer (score 0):

You can clone the div with id `editor` and put inside the clicked divs like this:

```
var $clone = $('#editor').clone();

$('div[id^="par"]').click(function(){
  $(this).append($clone);
});
```

[See the working example here](http://jsbin.com/opopu3)

Comment: clever, but i wouldn't want that since that will duplicate the ID's. any other approaches? thanks man!

Comment: @Martin Ongtangco: Which element's id are you talking about?

Comment: Maybe i haven't explained my problem thoroughly. my apologies. I'm using telerik controls where in i can't just re-generate a control (like a datepicker) via javascript. Those set of controls generate unique ID's to each element (input DOMs), so appending it won't work as what a normal input box will, based on your example.